# QTextEdit - get selection line numbers

Tags: c++, qt, text, qt4, qtextedit

I have the following code (implemented in the mouseReleaseEvent) to detect when the user has selected lines of text:

```
    QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
    int start = cursor.selectionStart();
    int end = cursor.selectionEnd();

    if(!cursor.hasSelection())
        return; // No selection available

    qWarning() << "start: " << start << " end: " << end << endl;
```

the problem is: I need the line numbers where the selection begins and ends. I've been struggling with blocks and solved nothing, can you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, that it isn't the best solution, but it seems to work for me. The variable `selectedLines` will contain, how many lines are selected.

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();
int selectedLines = 0; //<--- this is it 
if(!cursor.selection().isEmpty())
{
    QString str = cursor.selection().toPlainText();
    selectedLines = str.count("\n")+1;
}
```

I hope, that it will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I see easy way to use chain of 2 QTextCursor methods - setPosition and blockNumber.

```
QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
int start = cursor.selectionStart();
int end = cursor.selectionEnd();

if(!cursor.hasSelection())
    return; // No selection available

cursor.setPosition(start);
int firstLine = cursor.blockNumber();
cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
int lastLine = cursor.blockNumber();
qWarning() << "start: " << firstLine << " end: " << lastLine << endl;
```

UPD:

```
 cursor.setPosition(start);
 cursor.block().layout()->lineForTextPosition(start).lineNumber();
 // or
 cursor.block().layout()->lineAt(<relative pos from start of block>).lineNumber();
```

Set position to begin of selection. Get current block, get layout of block and use Qt API for getting line number. I doesn't know which line number returned is absolute for whole document or for layout. If only for layout, you need some additional process for calculate line numbers for previous blocks.

```
for (QTextBlock block = cursor.block(). previous(); block.isValid(); block = block.previous())
    lines += block.lineCount();
```

Comment: There's a problem: I knew how to do this before you posted, but I'm trying to get LINE numbers, not block numbers. Block != lines, and in my document there are two-lines blocks, so I can't use your code